# Kendo Grid update field in inline editing mode

Tags: kendo-grid

I am trying to update Kendo Aspnet core grid field while adding a new record in inline editing.

Here are more details.

Start adding a new row in grid -> add programically content to the edit fields.

I have a grid with textArea field called VideoSubtitleText which I am trying to update using javascript code.

Here is my js code

```
 let ttt = $("#VideoSubtitleText").kendoTextArea().data("kendoTextArea");


 ttt.value("New subtitle text");
 ttt.trigger("change");
```

Here is my grid

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<VideoSubtitle>
     ()
     .Name("subtitlegrid")
     .Filterable()
     .Editable()

     
     .Selectable(selectable => selectable
     .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
     .Scrollable()
     .ClientDetailTemplateId("templateSubtitleStyle")
     .ToolBar(toolbar =>
     {

         toolbar.ClientTemplateId("GridToolbarTemplate");
     })

     .Columns(columns =>
     {

         columns.Bound(column => column.VideoSubtitleBeginTimeStr).Title("Start Time").Width(70).Filterable(false);
         columns.Bound(column => column.VideoSubtitleEndTimeStr).Title("End Time").Width(70).Filterable(false);
         columns.Bound(column => column.VideoSubtitleText).Title("Text").Width(380).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "wrap" });

         columns.Command(column =>
         {                                                
             column.Edit();
             column.Destroy();
         }).Width(140);

     })
     .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
     .Sort(sort => sort.Add("VideoSubtitleBeginTimeStr").Ascending())
     .Read(r => r.Url("/VideoDataDetails?handler=ReadSubtitles").Data("forgeryToken"))
     .Update(u => u.Url("/VideoDataDetails?handler=UpdateSubtitle").Data("forgeryToken"))
     .Create(c => c.Url("/VideoDataDetails?handler=CreateSubtitle").Data("forgeryTokenAndLocale"))
     .Destroy(d => d.Url("/VideoDataDetails?handler=DestroySubtitle").Data("forgeryToken"))

     .Model(m => m.Id(id => id.VideoSubtitleId))
     .Events(ev => ev.RequestEnd("gridRequestEnd"))

     )

     .Events(events => events
     .Change("onSubtitleSelected")
     .Save("onSaveSubtitle")
     .SaveChanges("onSaveSubtitle")
     .Remove("onRemove")
     .Edit ("onSubtitleEdit")

     )


     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 600px;" })

 )
```

This code updates the grid field (VideoSubtitleText) correctly first time.
However I need to update same field multiple times. This causes problem and extra  element is added each time when field is updated from my js code.

Here is image showing the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELCtu.png)

The code updates the field but additional html elements are created when multiple updates are done to the same field